# One part of my javascript works the other does not

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a calculate function and the a canvas element I'm not sure why but the canvas part works and the calculate function does not. if I launch this from my text editor the calculate function works and the canvas part does not.

Its really got me confused and I think it may have something to do with the ordering maybe I'm really not sure can someone please explain these results?

http://jsfiddle.net/IamSleepy32/tELZd/

this is the calculate function

```
function calculate(){
var amount=document.getElementById("amount");
var apr=document.getElementById("apr");
var years=document.getElementById("years");
var payment=document.getElementById("payment");
var total=document.getElementById("total");
var totalintrest=document.getElementById("totalintrest");

var principal= parseFloat(amount.value);
var intrest= parseFloat(apr.value)/100/12;
var payments= parseFloat(years.value)*12;

var x= Math.pow(1+intrest,payments);
var monthly= (principal*x*intrest)/(x-1);

if(isFinite){
    payment.innerHTML=monthly.toFixed(2);
    total.innerHTML=(monthly*payments).toFixed(2);
    totalintrest.innerHTML=((monthly*payments)-principal).toFixed(2);

}
else{
    payment.innerHTML="";
    total.innerHTML="";
    totalintrest.innerHTML="";
    }
}
```

This is the beginning of canvas part the rest is in the fiddle

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the function calculate was undefined. I tweaked your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tELZd/10/) a bit and actually divided the js code into two sections:

```
function calculate() {}
```

can be placed in the head part of the html and the drawing of the canvas can happen in the onLoad event. Also take @campari's advise into account about the isFinite as this might be undefined. I've replaced it with

```
if(true)
```

Comment: Can I ask why it was undefined? was it because it was not in the head? if so how do I know what types of js should be in the head and which types should be in the body?

Comment: functions that you don't need immediately can be put in the head. Nevertheless, I'd recommend to put all your js or in the head section but in different, logical functions or in separate js files

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see within your function is that you're using an undefined variable `isFinite`. If you were refering to the JavaScript function [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite), then you forgot to specify the numeric parameter.

Perhaps you meant,

```
if (isFinite(monthly)) { } else { }
```